# Python 3.5 Theano ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: anaconda, theano, python-3.5

I'm using Anaconda for Python 3.5 and the Theano library. I followed the instruction of deeplearning.net and tried to run a simple piece of code to test the library but it got an irritating error.
Here is the code:

```
import numpy
import theano.tensor as T
from theano import function

x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x+y
f = function([x, y], z) //The error comes from this line
```

And the stack trace of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/1st sem - 16-17/FYP - Neural Network/firstTest/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    f = function([x, y], z)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function.py", line 320, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 479, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1777, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1641, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\link.py", line 690, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1003, in make_all
    no_recycling))
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 970, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 879, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1200, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1143, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1595, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1142, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1506, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2213, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 299, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.
```

Comment: anyone knows the answer of this please? :(

Comment: Have you tried setting your .theanorc to point to the g++ compiler found in Anaconda3\envs\[py35]\MinGW\bin\g++.exe? Where [py35] is just whatever you chose to name your python environment as.